# Why does the standard form of the first order linear ODE exclude non-linear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From Boyce and DiPrima, the standard form a first order linear ODE is:

$$ \frac{\textrm{d}y(t)}{\textrm{d}t} + p(t)y(t) = q(t)$$

What if $p(t) = y(t)$? Then, I would have a non-linear ODE? So, how does the standard form exclude non-linear ODEs without requiring that $p(t) \neq y(t)$?

Comment: You may think of it like the equation is linear in variables $y'$ and  $y$. For a simple example, consider an algebraic linear equation in two variables: $$ax_1 + bx_2 = c$$ Letting $b=x_2$ makes it non linear.

Comment: That form only applies when $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are known functions. If $p(t) = y(t)$ then you don't know it anymore therefore the equation is non-linear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More specifically, the definition in Boyce and DiPrima states that $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are given, or known functions of $t$.

Thus, if $p(t) = y(t)$, then the problem is solved since $p(t)$ is known.

So, the definition is implicitly talking about cases where $p(t) \neq y(t)$.